# maven-failsafe-plugin: Groups are getting ignored when setUp parameterized Test

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin, parameterized-tests

I have configured the maven-failsafe-plugin for excluding/including some testcategories:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <groups>my.company.SomeImportantCategory</groups>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now I have a parameterized test which is NOT annotated with `SomeImportantCategory`:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@Category(AnotherCategory.class)
public class SomeTestIT {

    @Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Collection<TestData[]> setUp() throws Exception {
        // Loading Some Excel-Sheets. I'm using github.com/fhm84/jexunit
        return doSomethingVeryTimeConsuming("with/this/excel-file.xls");
    }
}
```

Now I run the integration-tests with this profile. Maven does execute the setUp-Method for collecting test-cases.

Do you know how to skip this?
It would be ok for me to access the setUp-Method and do some Java-magic like reading out the included/excluded Groups (how?!?) and skipping `doSomethingVeryTimeConsuming` using reflection.

Comment: Have you checked to use the most recent version of maven-failsafe-plugin? See https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

Comment: Yes, I tried 2.19.1, but there I had problems with our include/exclude-Patterns. We decided to stay on 2.18.1

Comment: Can you show the full pom file which shows the whole configuration for maven-failsafe-plugin etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. The problem was that I marked the tests with `@Category`, however forgot to rebuild the artifact and was running them against the old one with `mvn failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify`...

```
mvn clean package
```

solved everything to me.

In case someone finds this question in google, just like I did :)